# cmake external project properties list

Tags: cmake

I use `ExternalProject_Add` command in my `CMakeLists.txt` for adding some external project. I'd like to retrieve some project properties (exactly I'd like to get preprocessor definitions like `<project>_DEFINITIONS` from `Find<package>.cmake`).

Is there any way to get all allowed project properties for using as `ExternalProject_Get_property` command parameter? For example, I know about *source_dir* and *binary_dir*, i. e. something like this:

`ExternalProject_Get_property(<my project> binary_dir)`

OR is there any way to use `find_package` function immediately after dowloading external project? I definitely know that `find_package` for this project works after launching build (i. e. after external project is already configured). It automatically sets all necessary variables (like `<project>_DEFINITIONS`), but obviously `find_package(<project>)` is not available initially (i. e. before external project was configured).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you download external package, you have **only its sources**. CMake has no common way for extract information about the package using only its sources.

**Only sources**:

Function `ExternalProject_Get_property` returns properties which are *set* by `ExternalProject_Add` call itself. The external project hasn't even configured at this call, so you cannot get any information about the package.

**Configured**:

There is command [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/export.html), which allows for configured external package to publish information about some of its targets.

**Installed**:

Command `find_package` requires (normally) the package to be already installed.

Comment: OK, thanks. And is there any way to force *configuration* or *building* for external project **before** building project source tree itself?

Comment: Command [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) performs its actions *immediately* on configuration stage. If you call this command **before** `find_package` and say it to build the external project, then `find_package` will finds the project.

Comment: That can't be true, since it should e.g. possible to get the `binary_dir` even without setting it - CMake should autoselect something.

Comment: In the phrase "... properties which are set by `ExternalProject_Add` call itself." I mean properties which are defined, *explicitely or implicitely*, according to [ExternalProject_Add documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html). As `BINARY_DIR` property is defined in any case, you may extract it with `ExternalProject_Get_property` command.